# Appsody :: Run simple node js express application gives error ( MacBook Pro - M1 -2020 )

Tags: node.js, docker, apple-m1, appsody

I am trying to run node js application by using appsody. I have installed [appsody](https://appsody.dev/docs/installing/macos/) using brew and made project by running `appsody init nodejs-express` command.

Now when I run `appsody run command`. I get the below error. I have pulled ubuntu image from docker hub ( `docker pull ubuntu` ) and agin run this command but no success.

Steps I did

```
brew install appsody/appsody/appsody
appsody list
mkdir my-project
cd my-project
appsody init nodejs-express
appsody run
```

Getting below error

```
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Does that command write out a PNG file, or text-format error messages?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Just from what you've included in the text it's a little hard to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes the command gives error you can check the third last line in the image

Comment: ...then please include the code that generates the image.  I can't run the image or search for it, so if the only output of the program is the image file it's not going to be easy to find similar problems.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the [appsody/init-controller](https://hub.docker.com/r/appsody/init-controller/tags) image is not available for your native platform (which is `linux/arm64/v8`). If you click the link (earlier in this sentence) and look at the "Tags" tab on Docker Hub you'll see this image is only being published for `linux/amd64` (Intel) and two other platforms, but not for ARM64.

To make this work, you need to specify another platform. You can do that by setting this environment variable before running the application:

```sh
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

**NOTE:** Docker can do this emulation (running amd64 on ARM) using qemu, but it is sometimes unstable. You may find the containers crash. But other times it works fine; YMMV.

Another option could be to rebuild all the needed images as ARM64. To do this you'd need to identify all of the images that matter, and try to find source material to rebuild them. Sometimes those are available (e.g. on GitHub) - other times they are not published. So this may not be an option for you.

Comment: I am running the app using appsody where do i WRITE this COMMAND ?

Comment: @UsmanIqbal I would try writing it at your prompt before you run appsody.

Answer (score 0):

Any one who is running docker by appsody and face the above problem below command worked for me.

The gist is to concatenate your command with @Dan Lowe command.

```
     {
        "label": "Appsody: debug",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64;appsody debug --network my-microservice_default --docker-options '--env KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:xxxx' -p xxxx:xxxx -p xxxx:xxxx -p xxxx:xxxx",
        "group": "build",
        "problemMatcher": []
    },
```